# How can I put a String message with a line break in gherkin?

Tags: cucumber, gherkin, cucumber-java

> 

Example: Then I get the message "Registration successful

Welcome Administrator"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use doc strings in Gherkin:

```
Then the message reads
"""
Hello

World
"""
```

In your step definition you can use the `String` parameter type.